# How to remove extra square bracket from result array object?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, codeigniter

This is my result JSON and i am trying to remove extra square brackets but nothing worked

```
 "feedList": [
        [             // Want to remove this brackets 
            {
                "feed_id": "1",
                "feed_user_id": "31",
                "feed_privacy": "1",
                "modified_date": "2021-04-23 13:51:05"
            }
        ],            // Want to remove this brackets 
        [             // Want to remove this brackets 
            {
                "feed_id": "1",
                "feed_user_id": "31",
                "feed_privacy": "1",
                "modified_date": "2021-04-23 13:51:05"
            }
        ]           // Want to remove this brackets 
       ]
```

I wanted to remove extra square brackets, this is my SQL result and trying to get it proper nothing worked

Please Help

```
foreach ($dataArray as $friend)
{
    if (in_array($user_id, $dataArray))
    {
        $query_s = $this
            ->db
            ->where('feed_user_id', $user_id)->get('tbl_feed');
        $result_f = $query_s->result();
    }
    else
    {
        $query_f = $this
            ->db
            ->where('feed_user_id', $friend)->where('feed_privacy', 2)
            ->get('tbl_feed');
        $result_f = $query_f->result();
    }
    if (!empty($result_f)) 
    $allData[] = $result_f;
}
return $allData;
```

This is the code that produces the above result

Comment: Please post the code that generates this since that's where you should do the change (and we don't know what you need to change without seeing what you're currently doing)

Comment: _“and trying to get it proper nothing worked”_ - show us what you actually tried then, instead of giving us such statements that are void of _any_ useful information.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Have added the code that produces the result, Hoping for an answer

Comment: Your `$result_f` is probably an array with an object or another array within it. This looks like a framework's database abstraction - what are you using?

Comment: @El_Vanja PHP Codeigniter framework

Comment: Side note: checking `if (in_array($friend, $dataArray))` inside `foreach ($dataArray as $friend)` makes no sense - this will always be true. You're checking if the element of the array you're iterating is an element of that array. What did you try to do here?

Comment: Oh wait! I know what's going on. The function `result()` always returns an array of records, while your queries only seem to return a single record. So `$allData` contains multiple result arrays from different queries. Tbh, you should rethink this from the ground up. If your `in_array()` returns true (which it always will as @El_Vanja pointed out), you'll just fetch the same records over and over. What exactly are you trying to do with this code? What does the database look like, what does it contain (example data), what does all the variables contain and what are you really trying to do?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I have mistakenly put the same variable `in_array` function  which I have updated and yes my queries will get multiple numbers of records that is why I used `result()` i am trying to get all feeds from my  friends ( `dataArray` having friend ids) which having `feed_privacy=2` and all my feeds which is `user_id` and not having any privacy

Answer (score -1):

use `array_merge($allData,$result_f);` instead of `$allData[] = $result_f;`

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What is the problem and how does your code solve it?